# Component returned failure code: 0x80460001 (NS_ERROR_CANNOT_CONVERT_DATA) [nsIDOMFormData.append]

Tags: forms, javascript

We're building a drupal-site with an upload form. Not webform.

When we click on the "insert image" button we get alerted with "Component returned failure code: 0x80460001 (NS_ERROR_CANNOT_CONVERT_DATA) [nsIDOMFormData.append]" from Firefox. Works in Chrome though.

Traced the problem down to being some sort of error from Firefox's engine, HOWEVER, I also noticed this module when searching for the error, in particular #6:
http://drupal.org/node/1386294. It works perfectly when we do it through the controlpanel BUT NOT when we print the form out.

I'm sorry if the question is too specific or is placed in the wrong category.